# How to trim all string properties of a class instance?

Tags: arrays, typescript, string, trim, typing

I have an instance of some class.
Let's say this class is Person:

```
class Person {
    name?: string | null;
    age?: number | null;
    friends!: Person[];
    isLucky: boolean;
}
```

How to iterate over this instance and call trim() method on all properties that are strings? Because if I'm trying to do this:

```
(Object.keys(person) as (keyof typeof person)[]).forEach((key) => {
  const value = person[key];
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    person[key] = value.trim();
  }
});
```

My friend Typescript shows this error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'person[keyof person]'.
```

I want to write an all around method suitable for instances of different classes with many different properties.
Is there a way to achieve this in Typescript? May be some typing magic?

Comment: What do you get when you console log value after the line const value = person[key]; ?

Comment: You get a value of a person's property named key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way. Just cast it to `any`.

```js
(Object.keys(person) as (keyof typeof person)[]).forEach((key) => {
  const value = person[key];
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    (person as any)[key] = value.trim();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript isn't able to determine if the key is associated with a specific typed key from Person, only that it's one of them. So you'll get a type of `never` when accessing `person[key]` without any other specific checks on `key`.

The quickest answer is to narrow your key:

```ts
(Object.keys(person) as (keyof typeof person)[]).forEach((key) => {
  const value = person[key];
  if (key === 'name' && typeof value === 'string') {
    person[key] = value.trim();
  }
});
```

Alternatively you could do the `.trim()` in your class constructor and avoid this entirely, but it's unclear what the context is for your issue.

Generally I avoid doing a `forEach` to map an Object and might favor `Object.from` over an `Object.entries` with a `.map()` or reconsider the data structure entirely depending on what your actual use case might be.

Comment: The use case is I just want to trim my database properties every time before updating by utilizing lifecycle hooks.